# Printar em imagens com a biblioteca pillow

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, for, pillow

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto de emissão automática de certificados onde uso o `pandas` para puxar os nomes de uma planilha e o Pillow para escrever o nomes no certificado.

O problema ocorre na impressão dos nomes na imagem. Utilizei o `for` para percorrer o array de nomes e escrever cada um em uma imagem, mas o que ocorre é que todos os nomes são escritos em uma imagem apenas, com somente o primeiro nome da lista em uma imagem separada.

Já tentei utilizar o `while` e o `def` mas só obtive mais bugs. Meu código abaixo:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
import pandas as pd


pessoas = pd.read_excel(r"pessoas.xlsx")
nome = (pessoas['NOME'])

# Definir o modelo do certificado e as fontes que serão utilizadas
im = Image.open('certificado.png')
fnt = ImageFont.truetype("font/Twenty One.ttf", 50)
fnt2 = ImageFont.truetype("font/Cinzel-Regular.otf", 20)

texto = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
date = ['10/10/1000',(155, 300)]  # cordenadas da data da emissão
inst = ['Instituição', (485, 300)] # cordenadas do nome da INSTITUIÇÃO

# Cordenadas - NOME // DATA // INSTITUIÇÃO
cord = [(230, 210),(155, 300),(485, 300)]

for x in nome:
    texto.text(cord[0], x, font=fnt, fill=('black'))
    texto.text(cord[1], date[0], font=fnt2, fill=('black'))
    texto.text(cord[2], inst[0], font=fnt2, fill=('black'))
    im.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VOcê só tem uma instância da imagem que é criada no momento em que você chama `Image.open` - Se você simplesmente mover esta linha, e a linha que cria  o objeto `texto` para dentro do `for` vai funcionar.

Mas é um bom código paa você entender melhor como funcionam funções, em vez de tentar só empilhar uma linha embaixo da outra - 
Você pode ter uma função que receba os parâmetros abra a imagem, escreva o texto, e devolva a nova imagem - e seu `for` pode ter uma linha só.

Comment: impressionado de como foi simples resolver haha muito obrigado não tinhha me atentado a isso
ja havia tentado criar um função com esses parametros e dava o mesmo problema mas seguindo sua dica funcionou muito bem